# RewriteRule doesn't seem to work, but RedirectMatch does

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use a RewriteRule to redirect requests for URLs to an updated URL string. This is for a WordPress site.

/category-about
/category-about-pagename

Should redirect to:
/category/category-about
/category/category-about-pagename

This rule: `RedirectMatch permanent ^/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1-$2/` seems to do the trick nicely. However, it seems to mess up /wp-admin by redirecting wp-admin requests to /wp/wp-admin.

I tried to use a rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1-$2/ [L,R=301]
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect and the rewrite rule doesn't seem to work, whereas the redirectmatch did.

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1-$2/ [L,R=301]
```

`Leading slash` doesn't match in `.htaccess` since this is applied per directory.

Comment: I owe you a frothy mug of your favorite beverage, sir. =)

One last question, how could I write a rewrite conditional to exclude files with an .html extension?

Comment: You're most welcome. For that `.html` skipping you can have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$`

Comment: Good sir, would it be possible to ask you to have a look at this question as well? http://goo.gl/hyCtNG